# Stuck trying to find unbounded $s_n$ with $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n s_k\rightarrow L$

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

I proved that if a sequence $(s_n)$ converges to a limit $s$ then so does its "average sequence," $(\sigma_n)$ with $\sigma_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n s_k$.  I found a counterexample for the converse, where $\sigma_n$ converges to a limit but $s_n$ doesn't (a stupid example is $(-1)^n$).  Now I am stuck trying to find an example where $\sigma_n$ converges to a (finite) limit, $s_n$ does not, and $s_n$ is unbounded.  (Note that we can't have $s_n\rightarrow \infty$ or $s_n\rightarrow -\infty$.)

I've tried $(-1)^nn$, $(-1)^n\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, $\left\lfloor \frac{-1 + \sqrt{8n+1}}{2}\right\rfloor$... but they don't work.  I'm stuck.  I just can't think of an example.  I feel like this is going to smack me in the face.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Work out what $s_n$ needs to be so that $\sigma_n = (-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$.

The reason this seemed reasonable is that for any sudden swing in $\sigma_n$, there needs to be a corresponding value of $s_n$ about $n$ times larger than the swing.

Comment: I'm going to need a bigger hint.  I can't figure it out.  $(-1)^n\sqrt{n}$ doesn't work.

Comment: You mean if you choose that as $s_n$? I'm not sure if that works, but it's not what I was suggesting. You can calculate $s_n$ exactly if you've decided what $\sigma_n$ is. Can you express $s_n$ in terms of the sequence $\sigma_n$?